# Powershell alias for opening a file on disk

Tags: powershell

I often store useful scraps of information in a file called scraps.md on my Windows 10 machine. However, if the file isn't open, it is a pain to navigate to the folder containing the file in the powershell and then opening it.

Can I make a command called, say, `openscraps` which opens up `scraps.md` in the emacs editor?

In bash, I would have made an alias of this using `alias openscraps="emacs <path-to-scraps-file>/scraps.md"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Invoke-Item in a function should do the trick assuming emacs is the default editor for .md-files. You could replace Invoke-Item with path to emacs if not.

```
function openscraps { Invoke-Item <path\to\scraps.md> }
```

or

```
function openscraps { <path\to\emacs> <path\to\scraps.md> }
```